# Apply Diff in PHP

Tags: php, diff, pear, patch

I'm working with the Text_Diff PEAR package to diff to short text documents, where the Text_Diff object is created with a space-delimited list of the words in each document.  I was hoping to store the diff in a database, and then apply it when the file is loaded again.  Is there an easy way to apply this diff, or do I need to write a function to parse it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The php xdiff extension supports patching from both files and strings. Looking at the source for Text_Diff I see that it uses xdiff for performing the diffs. You should be able to patch using [xdiff_string_patch()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xdiff-string-patch.php) or some of it's sibling functions.